# crop canvas html5 to image as base64 on client side without server-side code

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, jcrop

I have an image source like http://socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png and no FileReader object.

I need to crop this image from different domain using client-side JavaScript only.

When I am trying to get source from canvas (canvas.toDataURL()) I get a Security Error (unsecure operation).

In summary:

1. Is there a way to avoid this error? If I need to use CORS (crossOrigin) for the server/client then please provide example on the server-side settings;
2. Is there any hack to prevent this error?
3. Is it possible to combine 3 operations (crop, rotate, zoom) on canvas and then get a source of image as Base64?
4. It would be great to have a working example.

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not any more. (Link to enabling CORS on server: http://enable-cors.org/)
2. Not any more.
3. Yes.
4. Annotated code example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gz6e8/

Once you have properly configured your server for CORS you can download an image that won't taint your canvas like this:

```
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.src="http://yourConfiguredServer.com/logo.png";
```

Illustration of the results:

[image]

Comment: just a quick question:
If I change the source of the img object to the big image (http://whatdigitalcamera.media.ipcdigital.co.uk/11133/00000873b/1ea7/Sony-A7-sample-image-9.jpg) then onload function is not fired. Any idea?
http://jsfiddle.net/gz6e8/1/

Comment: Yes, this other image is not hosted on a CORS compliant site.  Therefore you are experiencing a cross-domain access error.  If that's your server you must CORS enable your site using the link in #1 of my answer.  If that's not your server then you can move the image to your server--and CORS enable your server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an error but a security feature of your browser since your canvas gets tainted when you load cross domain content.

You could possibly avoid this by settings your http headers on your server. But it all comes down to ho the specifik browser interprets your code!